# What is the difference between str.find and str.index methods in python

Tags: python-2.7, methods

I want to know what is different to write in the shell  *for example* **str.find("n")** and **str.index("n")**

Comment: try : 'aa'.find('b') , 'aa'.index('b')  or  help(''.find) etc

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Answer (score 1):

[According to documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=index#string.index)

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
```

Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in  s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

```
string.index(s, sub[, start[, end]])
```

Like find() but **raise ValueError when the substring is not found.**